# Throttle concurrent build is not working in parallel

Tags: jenkins, parallel-processing, executors

I am using Throttle concurrent plugin for parallel execution in Jenkins. I have one master jenkins node with 4 executors. Now I want to run my build in parallel, I have configured the build with number of concurrent build:0 and number of executors per node:3 and when I build it..It is not executing in parallel, only one build is triggered. Kindly help me to resolve this problem.
checked option : "Execute concurrent build if neccessary" in jenkins for this job

Comment: build with number of concurrent build:>0

Comment: Tried with number of concurrent build> 0 (with 2 and 3) also..but it is not working in parallel..only single build is triggered..

Comment: checked option : "Execute concurrent build if neccessary" in jenkins for this job